# Where does setuptools find the version of a package?

Tags: python, release, setuptools

I am trying to understand what version a [github package](https://github.com/pycontribs/jira) has. I am building it locally. In the [release process](https://github.com/pycontribs/jira/blob/develop/release.sh#L5), I find this:

```
VERSION=$(python setup.py --version)
```

In my repo, whenever I run this I get:

```
» python setup.py --version
1.0.9.dev29
```

But I have no clue where this is coming from. The version `1.0.9.dev29` is neither in the `setup.cfg`, nor in a separate `VERSION` file. There is no version file or similar in the repo. I do not understand how `setuptools` is able to derive this version id. The [documentation](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html) does not give any hints.

How does the `python setup.py --version` command work?

Comment: Have you looked at `setup.py` yet? :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: yes, and it has nothing related to the version (I had to reorg the links, they were wrong). I *do* think that --version gives me the version of the package, not of setuptools.

Comment: It looks as though the package in question is using [pbr](https://docs.openstack.org/developer/pbr/); the answer to where the version comes from is probably in the pbr documentation somewhere. In particular: "In both cases version strings are inferred from git." So it looks as though the version is based on the most recent tagged git revision.

Comment: Indeed, I got it wrong and `--version` produces the `version` field in the metadata. This specific project uses a third-party project called `pbr` to set that up.

Comment: @MarkDickinson makes sense, can accept as answer. I do not know how you did infer that it was using pbr

Comment: @delavnog: I got lucky: I looked at `jira/__init__.py` on GitHub (because that's one of the locations that one might expect to find version information) and noticed that the most recent commit to that file had a message "Adopted pbr and hacking". (The `from pbr.version` import was a bit of a giveaway, too.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setup.py --version` lists the version of a package taken from the metadata. Your specific project uses the [`pbr` package](https://docs.openstack.org/developer/pbr/) to handle metadata:

```
setup_requires=['pbr>=1.9', 'setuptools>=17.1', 'pytest-runner'],
```

`pbr` (*Python Build Reasonableness*) sets a version at package build time by looking at the current git history, see the [*Version* section](https://docs.openstack.org/developer/pbr/#version) of the `pbr` documentation:

> Versions can be managed two ways - postversioning and preversioning. Postversioning is the default, and preversioning is enabled by setting version in the setup.cfg metadata section. In both cases version strings are inferred from git.
>
> If the currently checked out revision is tagged, that tag is used as the version.

So when the developer runs `setup.py` to build a distribution, *at that time* `pbr` looks at the git repository metadata and extracts a version number, and includes that in distributions that are built; the `tar.gz` source tarball includes a `PKG-INFO` file with the version.

Answer (score 0):

Per the accepted answer, the info is coming from your git repo, based on tags, using the `pbr` extension.

What's not included is how the actual string was determined. `pbr` uses an algorithm that is specified in the `pbr` documentation based on the latest tags that were created in the repo (I'm assuming searching the currently checked out branch, but not sure).

The `1.0.9.dev29` string likely means you have a `1.0.9` tag in the repo, with 29 commits that do not have a tag. By default, `pbr` will add a `.devN` postfix to a new commit without a tag, that increments with each new untagged commit.

If you add a `1.0.10` tag to the latest commit, that will be the new version, but if you add another commit without a tag, it will be `1.0.9.dev30`.

See [here for More info on the Semantic Versioning used by `pbr`](https://docs.openstack.org/pbr/latest/user/semver.html)